# Installing only dev dependencies with pipenv

Tags: docker, pipenv

I have a docker image which I use as my base production image and then another image used for testing which inherits from the base image. I run `RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile` on the base image to install my dependencies. At the moment, on the test image, I run `RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile --dev` in order to install the dev dependencies, but this also installs the non-dev dependencies, which is redundant, since they were already installed on the base image. So, is there a way I can install *only* the dev dependencies when I run `pipenv install`?

Comment: To confirm, in your Pipfile.lock, are all your dependencies _indeed_ separated into a `[default]` and `[dev-packages]` sections?

Comment: Yes, I have both sections.

Comment: Doesn't the test image extend the base image? Do you expect the non-dev depenendencies to be uninstalled?